# passing data from activity to class in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-gallery

I have created on activity and I want to pass data from that activity to a class which extends Gallery. How can i pass data from activity to class as Intent doesn't work here.

Comment: What type of data? Objects, or just strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can create a `public static variable` then access that variable or you can create `getter` , `setter` method to get the value of the data in your second class.

Comment: i have tried getter setter method bt it dint work... i m trying with static variable

Comment: @MonalGodiwala plz appreciate the man if it really solved your problem..:) By accepting the answer so other may get some help of it

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) about the Gallery widget.

> This class was deprecated in API level 16. This widget is no longer
>   supported. Other horizontally scrolling widgets include
>   HorizontalScrollView and ViewPager from the support library.

Next, coming to your question. Keep whatever private variables you have in your class as private, and have a method that sets them for you (values passed as arguments). These act like regular setter methods in Java.

Invoke these setters on the instance of the new class you create.

Comment: thanks for informing.. i dint knw that Galley class is deprecated in API level 16..